# Not trivial scrolling question

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, .net-3.5, scroll

Suppose I have some header element and some content element in my window. I need the header element to horizontally scroll together with the content element. But when scrolling vertically the first should stay frozen while the second should scroll normally.
How can I do this?

I tried the following code

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
  <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <MyHeader DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
      <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel>
          <MyContent />
        </StackPanel>
      </ScrollViewer>
    </DockPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

But it seems the scrollviewwer's properties are inherited so this doesn't work.

Comment: are you talking about a Grid or what?

Comment: Yes, the scrolling behaviour should look similar to DataGrid (do you mean DataGrid?), but I have two separate elements for header pane and content pane. And content significatly differs from the DataGrid's one so I can't use it.